# Undefined error when embedding SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, svg

I' using an `ajax` call to retrieve an `htm` file that builds an `SVG`. The call returns the file successfully but the area where it's suppose to appear simply says:

[image]

Is this a timing issue? I have the ajax call in a separate `js` file that is called after the page loads.

```
function buildMap(){
    var lbmp = document.getElementById("lbmp-map");
    if(lbmp != null){
        $.ajax({ 
            url:'../footer.htm',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response){
                lbmp.innerHTML = response.responseText;
            },
            failure: function(response){
                lbmp.innerHTML = "<p>Failure</p>";
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you log the content of response in console ?

Comment: it's successful. It logs the code from `footer.htm` and you can access that file

Comment: Are you sure response.responseText is defined ? If using ajax, response should contains the html directly

Comment: @Gwendal that was the problem! It was throwing me off because the ajax call itself wasn't throwing any errors

Comment: Cool, I added an answer, can you mark it as accepted ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On success, ajax gives you directly the content, so your html is in `response` and not in `response.responseText`, that's why you are getting the `undefined` message.